# How to handle exception within trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, database-trigger

I want to add exception handling within trigger.

I created Trigger as below.

I want to add exception handling within that. So that my trigger never failed if there are any invalid condition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER system_notification_audit
 AFTER 
      INSERT OR 
      UPDATE 
on system_notification
FOR EACH ROW
    begin
insert into system_notification_log 
select :NEW.ID , :NEW.NAME, :NEW.Description, :NEW.PREFERENCE, :NEW.FREQUENCY, 
       :NEW.IS_HIGH, :NEW.IS_REQUIRED, :NEW.UPDATED_BY, :NEW.UPDATED_DATE
  from dual
 where :OLD.PREFERENCE <> :NEW.PREFERENCE 
 OR :OLD.FREQUENCY <> :NEW.FREQUENCY OR :NEW.IS_HIGH <> :OLD.IS_HIGH OR :NEW.IS_REQUIRED <> :OLD.IS_REQUIRED;
END;
```

Comment: you something like that `exception
   when others then
somthing..;`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-343E0653-9BCE-48F5-A00A-795D77B96B44

Answer (score 1):

Simply Ignoring an Exception isn't always a good way to design your program. At least log the errors somewhere for later observation.

Note that your `INSERT` statement can be rewritten using a simple `insert` ( without a `select` ) and an `IF` condition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER system_notification_audit AFTER
     INSERT OR UPDATE ON system_notification
     FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF
          :old.preference    <>:new.preference OR :old.frequency <>:new.frequency 
             OR :new.is_high <>:old.is_high OR :new.is_required  <>:old.is_required
     THEN
          INSERT INTO system_notification_log (
               id,
               name,
               description,
               preference,
               frequency,
               is_high,
               is_required,
               updated_by,
               updated_date
          ) VALUES (
               :new.id,
               :new.name,
               :new.description,
               :new.preference,
               :new.frequency,
               :new.is_high,
               :new.is_required,
               :new.updated_by,
               :new.updated_date
          );
     END IF;

 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  pr_trigger_logs(trig_name => 'system_notification_audit',
                    err_msg => DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE()); 
    -- calling an error logging procedure.
END;
/
```

I won't give you the definition of procedure `pr_trigger_logs`. As an exercise, I'll let you come up with it!.